# What software can I use to mirror my MIDI keyboard controller on-screen?

Tags: midi

I have a MIDI keyboard controller and I want to be able to mirror what I am playing on an onscreen keyboard, so that students in a music class can see it. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this thread](http://www.mac-forums.com/music-audio-and-podcasting/87744-screen-midi-keyboard-app.html) which talks about looking for "a piano keyboard app that would display the keys and also animate (push down) on the keys I play with my MIDI keyboard.", it seems like [an app called MidiKeys](http://www.manyetas.com/creed/midikeys.html) would do it.

The page in that link says "There is also an option to select a MIDI source and see incoming notes played on the keyboard.", and that sounds like what you're describing.

It also says "requires 10.5 to run", which probably means 10.5 or above, but it's possible that it means its only guaranteed to work on 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/

It can show what keys I play on my MIDI-keyboard.